# Routing engine that supports right sided pickups

Tags: openstreetmap, routing

I am using open street maps and I need to incorporate routing in to my application.  I know there are various routing engines that I can use, but I have a very specific requirement for the direction of travel along the road when the vehicle approaches a stop location.

Specifically this:

I am routing school buses.  Some roads are considered hazardous, which means that students are not allowed to cross the street to get on the bus.  In this situation, I would need the bus to be traveling in the proper direction to prevent the child from crossing the street.  On other (non-hazardous) roads, students are allowed to cross the street to load the bus.

I am currently using asp.net, c#, and javascript.  I would prefer an open source solution but would be willing to pay for something if I know it will fulfill my requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Our [RW Net 4](http://www.routeware.dk/rwnet4/rwnet.php) SDK provides support for "approach"-based routing, including optimizing the sequence (TSP) and avoiding u-turns.

Answer (score 0):

The Open Source project GraphHopper (written in Java) does not support this yet, but it should be fairly easy to implement. Additionally if you don't have the time/resources/.. to implement it we offer commercial support.